# How can I hide all elements containing another element with a particular class?

Tags: jquery, css

How can I hide all elements containing another element with a particular class ?

```
<div class="aa">
    Text 1 <span class="hideme">Show this !</span>
</div>
<div class="aa">
    Text 2
</div>
<div class="aa">
    Text 3
    <span class="qqq">Show this !</span>
</div>
```

In the above example the second and third div should be hidden and the first div (with "Text 1") with class bb, not just the span. And Text 3 should still be hidden as it is class .qqq instead of .hideme. It appears that :contains ignores classes and only works on plain text.

`$(".aa :not(:contains .hideme)".hide();`  hides *all* div's instead of only the div containing .hideme.

Comment: You can't do that with CSS, there is no parent selector in CSS

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla js, this is how to do it.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.aa').forEach(div => {
  div.style.display = 'none' 
  div.childNodes.forEach(child => {
    if (child.className == 'hideme') {
      child.style.display = 'none'
      div.style.display = 'block' 
    }
   
  })
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aa">
    Text 1 <span class="hideme">Show this !</span>
</div>
<div class="aa">
    Text 2
</div>
<div class="aa">
    Text 3
    <span class="qqq">Show this !</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all div and then use `$(".hideme").closest(".aa").show()` to show div where `hideme` is there . i.e :

```js
$(".aa").hide() //hide all
$(".hideme").closest(".aa").show() //show where hideme there
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aa">
  Text 1 <span class="hideme">Show this !</span>
</div>
<div class="aa">
  Text 2
</div>
<div class="aa">
  Text 3
  <span class="qqq">Show this !</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below loops through every `div` with `.aa` class and hides them if they do not contain any element with `.hideme` class.

I prefer this solution simply because it is a bit more user friendly - the elements are not hidden by default and the looping proccess is quite fast.

```js
$('.aa').each(function() {
  if( $(this).find('.hideme').length == 0 ) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aa">
  Text 1 <span class="hideme">Show this !</span>
</div>
<div class="aa">
  Text 2
</div>
<div class="aa">
  Text 3
  <span class="qqq">Show this !</span>
</div>
```